# How to install Privoxy on Centos 6

Tags: linux, installation, centos, privoxy

What is the procedure to install Privoxy on a Centos machine?
I have tried `yum install privoxy`, however, I get `No package privoxy available.`

I am unsure if I am supposed to add any additional repos or use an alternative method.

I have done a Google search for an answer but was unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These commands are more easier and manageable

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install privoxy -y
```

In future if you want to update

```
yum update privoxy -y
```

Ref: http://pkgs.org/centos-6/epel-x86_64/privoxy-3.0.21-3.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

Answer (score 0):

Enter these commands:

```
wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/rpm.razorsedge.org/centos-4/RE-test/privoxy-3.0.12-1.el4.re.i386.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh privoxy-3.0.12-1.el4.re.i386.rpm
sudo service privoxy start
```

Source: http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/

Comment: Shouldn't he be using packages for centos-6 rather than 4?

Comment: if you research centos6 you'd discover, a lot of redhat Ent 4 packages are fully qualified since they are based on the same base install. Also note before providing this answer I ran it in Virtualbox on fresh install of centos6 without issue.

Comment: Hi @tao thanks so much for the answer. I installed it with the exact instructions as you put them above, except for the sudo, since I am logged in as root, and I get sudo: command not found. Trying to run the service, I get: unrecognized service. Could you possibly help me solve this please. thanks in advance.